# Search Display Template in Tabular Form with specified columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

What is the starting point to create a search display template in a table format and be able to specify which columns you want to display. Presently, the default format only shows the title, description, and link in a 3 row list. I would like to change this to have title, description, link in 3 columns (table format) and be able to add or remove more columns.

What I have managed till now is create a search page for Tasks, that only searches for files of that specific content type. Now I want to be able to decide which columns are shown in the resulting view and if possible show them in a tabular format.

I was thinking about finding a similar template and try edit the HTML to make it look as I want it. Is there a similar template? Or perhaps a ready template which I missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was indeed a similar template, very similar to what I needed:

[Displaying SharePoint 2013 Search Results in a Table](https://www.itunity.com/blog/displaying-sharepoint-2013-search-results-table-877)

The table template html files are also provided for under an MIT License.